# What does multi_step in world_control.proto do?

Tags: control, gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am trying to execute several steps of Gazebo7 simulation by sending a `msgs::WorldControl` message to Gazebo where simulation is paused. In effect, I aim to advance the simulation by a varying amount of time. However, regardless of what number I pass using `msg.set_multi_step(m_stepCount)`, I cannot seem to advance by more than 1 iteration.

Did I misunderstand what multi_step does?

Relevant code excerpt from one of my experiments:

```
    void OnUpdate() 
    {
        // Throttle Publication
        gazebo::common::Time::MSleep(1000);

        m_step_count = m_step_count == 1 ? 700 : 1;

        msgs::WorldControl msg;
        msg.set_multi_step(m_step_count);
        this->pub->Publish(msg);

        // msgs::WorldControl stepMsg;
        // stepMsg.set_step(1);
        // this->pub->Publish(stepMsg);

        std::cout << "Publishing OnUpdate. Steps: " << m_step_count << std::endl;
    }
```

The result is that every second:

- Iteration increases by 1
- Sim Time increases by 00 00:00:00.001
- Real Time is increased by 00 00:00:01.000
- 700 or 1 are printed in the output string, alternating on every tick

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/20239/what-does-multi_step-in-world_control.proto-do?/) by [LinasKo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6270/linasko/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-08-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [LinasKo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6270/linasko/) on 2018-08-15**:
The issue has been solved, but I will keep this question open for answers regarding the effects of setting the multi_step field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

If you're using a world plugin, `OnUpdate` is called at every iteration within the physics thread. So I think what's happening is that you're introducing a 1 s sleep to every iteration - it will take 700 s until your 700 steps are processed.

I recommend you use a standalone program like [this one](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/5f09af2a3c6a78c8cfb88038a097a031ac0f8708/examples/stand_alone/publisher/?at=default) so you don't block the physics thread.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2018-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [LinasKo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6270/linasko/) on 2018-08-15**:
Is there a specific reason to not block the physics thread, as it seems to be exactly what I want to do. Basically, for cross-compatibility with another product I'm working on, I want to Sense -> run physics for time t0 -> Drive -> run physics for time t1 -> Repeat

**Comment by [LinasKo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6270/linasko/) on 2018-08-15**:
Ultimately, with your help, I think figured it out. I have removed `MSleep` and will block the OnUpdate until a volatile boolean value is updated from another thread, resuming the simulation, instead of trying to advance it by setting multi_step.

I am aware this might not be the best solution in the long term and will be investigating the more usual way of running it asynchronously as well. Thank you.